# How do I hide the mouse cursor when it is at the edge of the screen

Tags: x11, mouse

So when it reaches (or close to it) x 1920 then unclutter shoud be started what hides the cursor. And it should be killed when cursor leaves the edge.

How can I trigger that?

Thanks.

Im under arch linux and gnome shell. they shouldn't matter.

Comment: You need a window manager (WM) that supports this kind of effect. I'm not aware of any WM that has this feature, but I am not familiar with all WMs, in particular not `gwm` (which you need for Gnome, and yes, the WM matters).

Comment: Compiz has such a thing. Though there should be some event watcher or should be easily creatable.